# Are simple esters like those used as flavouring agents metabolised into their constituent carboxylic acids and alcohols in the human body?

Tags: human-biology, metabolism

By this I mean to ask whether say **ethyl butanoate** is hydrolysed in humans into *ethanol* and *butyric (butanoic) acid*. This is of interest to me as a pharmacology researcher because butyric acid, for instance, serves as a potent **histone deacetylase** (HDAC) inhibitor and hence increases gene expression but it has very poor oral bioavailability and I am curious as to whether there's any theoretical basis for suspecting that using butyric acid esters as prodrugs would be a more efficient way of delivering butyric acid.

Here is the molecular structure of ethyl butanoate:

[image]